# Play sounds on Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I wrote a quick test with `audio` in HTML5. It worked on Chrome, Firefox 3.6 and Opera but I haven't tested on Safari. It turns out Safari on Windows and iPod doesn't support this. I know Flash is used as a fallback for older browsers on some sites but that's not an option for the iPod.

How do I play sound on webpages? I see YouTube uses rtsp but I can't tell if that requires an app or not (its not my iPod) and seems like overkill?

Answer (score 2):

Safari only supports `.mp3` audio files - you need to convert the file from `.ogg` to `.mp3`, and include both with the `source` element, like this:

```
<audio> 
  <source src="sound.mp3" />
  <source src="sound.ogg" />
</audio>
```

Or use a feature detection script like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), allowing you to change the source based whether the browser supports it.

See also: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?  Add it as a javascript function...I believe that webkit supports it so it should work in iOS, Android, Chrome, and Safari.

```
var audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
audio.play();
```

Comment: yes, however i'll mention 1) I used an ogg file. 2) the file was from a different domain because my server wasnt sending the proper mime. It worked firefox, chrome, etc doesnt work on safari (windows), android and i tried just in case on ipod.